# Find the angle x in the regular octagon below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

In the plane figure below, we have a regular octagon $ABCDEFGH$, and I belongs to the diagonal $CG$, so that $\angle GIH = 30°$. Knowing this, determine in degrees the value of the angle indicated by x.(S:$75^o$)

[image]

Itry:

$a_i=\frac{180.(8-2)}{8} = 135^o $

$\angle IGH = \frac{135} {2}=67,5^o  \implies\angle IHG = 82,5^o$

$\angle AHB = \frac{180-135}{2}=22,5^o \implies \angle BHI  =135 - 82,5-22,5 = 30^o \cong \angle GIH$

[image]

I'm missing a relationship to finish that I didn't find

Comment: Are you open to a solution using trigonometry?

Comment: I get 75 degrees, do you know the answer?

Comment: @RobinSparrow  Yes, the correct answer is $75^o$

Comment: @DarkLordOfPhysics I would love to see a solution using trigonometry.

Comment: @Shadow I added it below! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Draw $IF$ and $HF$ and by symmetry you have an equilateral triangle so $HI=HF=HB$ so you have an isosceles $\triangle {BHI}$ with 30 degrees in the apex and thus $75$ degrees in the base angles.

Answer (score 3):

I will present an alternative approach using trigonometry. Let $L$ denote the length of the equal-length sides of the regular octagon $ABCDEFGH$. Applying the Law of Cosines to $\triangle BAH$, we find that $$(HB)^2 = (BA)^2 +(AH)^2 -2(BA)(AH) \cos(\angle BAH)=2L^2(1-\cos(135^{\circ}))$$ $$\implies HB = \left(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\right) L. \tag{1}$$ Now by the Law of Sines applied to $\triangle GIH$, $$\frac{\sin(\angle GIH)}{HG} = \frac{\sin(\angle HGI)}{IH} \implies \frac{\sin(30^{\circ})}{L} = \frac{\sin(\frac{135^{\circ}}{2})}{IH}$$ $$\implies IH = \left(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\right) L, \tag{2}$$ where we have made use of the half-angle identity $\sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)= \pm \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{2}}$ to compute an exact value for $\sin(67.5^{\circ})$. At this point, we have shown that $HB = \left(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\right) L = IH$. This is sufficient to conclude that $\angle IBH = \angle HIB$ (formally, we are applying the Law of Sines to $\triangle IBH$). Since the interior angles of $\triangle IBH$ sum to $180^{\circ}$, we moreover have $\angle IBH = \angle HIB = \frac{180^{\circ}-\angle BHI}{2} = 75^{\circ}$.

Comment: Nice solution! Had been hoping you’d do this after your comment.